# NumberFormatException.for InputString : "("

Tags: java, string, multithreading, exception, program-entry-point

While running my code I am getting a NumberFormatException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "("
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at collection.MyExpressionTrees.evaluateHelper(MyExpressionTrees.java:58)
    at collection.MyExpressionTrees.evaluateHelper(MyExpressionTrees.java:78)
    at collection.MyExpressionTrees.evaluate(MyExpressionTrees.java:50)



public class MyExpressionTrees extends MyBinaryTree {

public MyExpressionTrees() {

    root = null;

}

public MyExpressionTrees(MyBinaryTreeNode rt) {

    root = rt;

}

public int evaluate() {

    if (root == null) {
        return -1000000;
    }

    return evaluateHelper(root);

}

private int evaluateHelper(MyBinaryTreeNode rt) {

    if (rt.left == null) {

        return Integer.parseInt(rt.data.toString());

    }

    switch (rt.data.toString()) {

        case "+":

            return evaluateHelper(rt.left) + evaluateHelper(rt.right);

        case "-":

            return evaluateHelper(rt.left) - evaluateHelper(rt.right);

        case "/":

            return evaluateHelper(rt.left) / evaluateHelper(rt.right);

        case "*":

            return evaluateHelper(rt.left) * evaluateHelper(rt.right);

        case "%":

            return evaluateHelper(rt.left) % evaluateHelper(rt.right);

        default:

            return -1000000;

    }

}

}
```

Comment: The exception clearly tells you what the problem is!

Comment: how would you fix this problem

Comment: Don't try to convert `(` to an integer or catch the exception and handle it.

Comment: what would the  catch the exception and handle look like inside of the code

Comment: Read this thoroughly: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html  Then apply what you learned to your code.

Comment: It reality, your problem won't be solved by catching the exception.  You need to make sure that you don't put the `(` into the data in the first place.  Your parser has to deal with parentheses properly and ... build the tree differently

Comment: What would that look like In code

Comment: Where is the ( in the data

Answer (score 0):

[NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that the application
>   has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but
>   that the string does not have the appropriate format.

[public static int parseInt(String s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)):

> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters
>   in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first
>   character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a
>   negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a
>   positive value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if
>   the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the
>   parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.

"(" is not a number.

Aye, Famalam Fammy !

Comment: I know that but that what popped up when I ran the code in java. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "("

Answer (score 0):

public class Project_t {

```
private static final String fpath = "../COSC241_P4_Input.txt";

private static MyExpressionTree exTree = new MyExpressionTree();

private static List<String> infList;

private static final MyDeque d = new MyDeque();

private static final MyStack st = new MyStack();

private static int result;

/**
 *
 * Test method for the project. Handles file input and output, as well as *
 * running tests on each expression in the input file. *
 */
public static void test() {

    result = 0;

    File out = new File("../COSC241_P4_Output_tdreed0.txt");

    try {

        //Stores each line of the file in a list.
        infList = FP.readFile(fpath).stream().filter((s) -> !s.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        //If the output file does not currently exist, create it.
        if (!out.exists()) {

            out.createNewFile();

        }

        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out)) {

            for (String s : infList) {

                String root = s.trim().replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("\\[", "(").replaceAll("\\]", ")");

                writer.println("Original Infix:\t" + root);

                if (!ExpressionRegulators.allPMatched(root) || !ExpressionRegulators.allValid(root) || !ExpressionRegulators.isValidOrder(root)) {

                    writer.println("Invalid Expression");

                    writer.println();

                } else {

                    buildExpressionTree(root);

                    //Performs traversals on the tree
                    exTree.preorderTraversal();

                    writer.println("Preorder: " + exTree.preorderStr);

                    exTree.inorderTraversal();

                    writer.println("Inorder: " + exTree.inorderStr);

                    exTree.postorderTraversal();

                    writer.println("Postorder: " + exTree.postorderStr);

                    result = exTree.evaluate();

                    writer.println("Result: " + result);

                    writer.println();

                    exTree.clear();

                }

            }

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println(e.toString());

        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```